# Ckeditor 4.1.1 not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

I have downloaded a ckeditor 4.1.1 having following configuration in config.js

```
    CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
config.toolbarGroups = [
    { name: 'clipboard',   groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
    { name: 'editing',     groups: [ 'find', 'selection', 'spellchecker' ] },
    { name: 'links' },
    { name: 'insert' },
    { name: 'forms' },
    { name: 'tools' },
    { name: 'document',    groups: [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] },
    { name: 'others' },
    '/',
    { name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
    { name: 'paragraph',   groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align', 'bidi' ] },
    { name: 'styles' },
    { name: 'colors' },
    { name: 'about' }
];
config.removeButtons = 'Underline,Subscript,Superscript';
config.format_tags = 'p;h1;h2;h3;pre';
config.removeDialogTabs = 'image:advanced;link:advanced';
   };
```

While integrating with my php file, i used following text area and script as below:

```
<textarea class="text-input textarea" id="textarea" name="txtShortDescription" cols="79" rows="15"></textarea>
<textarea id="txtFullDescription" name="txtFullDescription" cols="79" rows="15"></textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">
CKEDITOR.replace( 'txtShortDescription');
CKEDITOR.replace( 'txtFullDescription' );   
</script>
```

The problem is the ckeditor is not showing as well as giving an error

```
  Error: TypeError: y is undefined
  Source File: http://<path>/ckeditor/ckeditor.js on line 42
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, its working.It was cache issue.You must clean browser cache in order to reflect changes